# Change Keyboard Orientation Without Flip The iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uikeyboard

I want to make the iOS device in a portrait mode and any keyboard will show in landscape mode. How can I manage such a thing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you want the view behind the keyboard to stay in portrait? Or do you want view behind keyboard and keyboard view to be in landscape, while everything else is portrait?

Comment: i want every thing in view behind the keyboard to stay in portrait but the keyboard be in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with setting the status bar's orientation.  This would require special handling to assure that your views won't rotate, but the keyboard, popovers, action sheets, etc. all take the orientation of the application's status bar.  Set the status bar's orientation like so:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:newOrientation]
```

Comment: I make the orientation disabled all over the application and for every view i want to make an orientation to it, i Rotate it manually, but i want to rotate the keyboard also.

Comment: Yes, but I think the only way to "rotate the keyboard" is to change the orientation of the status bar.  The keyboard always pops up opposite the status bar.  I don't think there is such a method as [keyboard setOrientation:].  Setting the status bar is the only way to do it as far as I know.

Comment: yes, i know it too. and the only way to it is draw your own keyboard and override iOS keyboard, but it's so hard.